# Executing JQAssistant with maven in a project with submodules with profiles

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, jqassistant

As the title shows i am using jqassistant with Maven. So far that worked well for small projects. Now i am using a project with multiple poms. As the guide tells (http://buschmais.github.io/jqassistant/doc/1.2.0/#_maven_plugin) i am only having this profile in the root-pom currently:

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>jqassistant</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.buschmais.jqassistant</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jqassistant-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.0</version>
                        <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>scan</goal>
                                <goal>analyze</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <failOnViolations>true</failOnViolations>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
      </build>


      <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.buschmais.jqassistant</groupId>
                <artifactId>jqassistant-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.0</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>report</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </reporting>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I also tried using the command useExecutionRootAsProjectRoot
However the build never scans the whole project. 
Subpoms have other profiles. Do i need the profile in every pom? Do i need to declare dependencies to jQA? Where - only in the parent pom?

Comment: Are the sub-modules referring to your root pom as parent?